# How to get information from callback after user succesfully authorizing my tweeter app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have managed to succesfully let users authorize my app agains tweeter with OAuth. The callback works too, but the problem is that the data this callback is returning into the resuming activiy is null. Do anybody know how to get it?

This is the code I'm executing to start the authentication:

```
consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", 
                "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", 
                "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,CALLBACK_URL);
Toast.makeText(this, "Please authorize this app!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
setConsumerProvider();

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
```

This is the manifest I'm using:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    ...    

    <activity android:name=".AuthActivity"  android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="Comparte en redes sociales" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="callback" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And this the resuming code for the `AuthActivity`:

```
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("RESUMING!!");
    if (this.getIntent()!=null && this.getIntent().getData()!=null)
    {

    }
}
```

Here the `this.getIntent().getData()` is null have been trying other options without luck. I need the data to extract the uri. Could anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, right after posting the question I found the problem. `launchMode="singleTask"` is making the activity recreate so, to get the uri I should be doing it into `onNewIntent` instead of onResume. Now the data is there ready to be read :). Sorry for the inconvenience.